# Latency jumps in first, middle and last mile of path

Tags: ping, wide-area-network, latency, traceroute

I work for SD-WAN company providing an all in one solution edge router(Like FORTINET but not FORTINET).

We have one customer in particular that has such a hard time with our services i.e. gift card servers unreachable, credit card processor unreachable and sometimes the security cameras don't send data back to the DC servers... Also the average ping to 4.2.2.1 is about 36ms but the avg ping to GC or CC processors is usually greater than 100ms.

We use Linux based platform with alot of utilities based on Open standards, e.g OpenVPN.

WAN circuits are my area of troubleshooting. I run pings and traceroutes and sometimes I see some crazy things. I have some traceroutes below and would like to see if the collective experience and brain power of this community can offer some possibilities.

I've taken the GW IP out, the rest I don't mind including.

### Heres a good example of a clean traceroute to 4.2.2.1

- Trace In Progress

traceroute to 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1), 30 hops max, 60
   byte packets

1  x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)  0.579 ms  0.679 ms  0.798 ms

2  76-202-64-1.lightspeed.brbnca.sbcglobal.net (76.202.64.1)  24.986
   ms  25.546 ms  25.666 ms

3  71.147.176.37 (71.147.176.37)  20.833
   ms  21.911 ms  22.035 ms

4  75.20.0.202 (75.20.0.202)  24.520 ms 
   24.838 ms  26.063 ms

5  12.83.38.157 (12.83.38.157)  30.335 ms 12.83.38.153 (12.83.38.153)  31.029 ms 12.83.38.157 (12.83.38.157)  30.416 ms

6  ggr2.la2ca.ip.att.net (12.122.128.101)  31.437 ms  24.566 ms  21.605 ms

7  192.205.37.146 (192.205.37.146)  23.534 ms  24.605 ms  25.294 ms

8  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  27.329 ms ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net
   (4.69.144.9)  28.090 ms ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net
   (4.69.144.73)  28.782 ms

9  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net
   (4.69.144.73)  28.938 ms ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net
   (4.69.144.9)  29.683 ms  30.287 ms

10  a.resolvers.level3.net
   (4.2.2.1)  29.979 ms  30.654 ms  31.089 ms

**Pretty good no problems. 
Lets look at the next example**

### This time an AT&T router's latency jumps WAY UP

- Trace In Progress

  traceroute to 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)  0.523 ms  0.637 ms  0.771 ms

2  76-202-64-1.lightspeed.brbnca.sbcglobal.net (76.202.64.1)  19.439 ms  29.179 ms  38.125 ms

3  71.147.176.37 (71.147.176.37)  20.750 ms  21.705 ms  22.158 ms

4  75.20.0.202 (75.20.0.202)  24.994 ms  25.144 ms  27.133 ms

5  12.83.38.153 (12.83.38.153)  29.790 ms  29.935 ms 12.83.38.157 (12.83.38.157)  31.198 ms

6  ggr2.la2ca.ip.att.net (12.122.128.101)  32.876 ms  25.446 ms  **280.808 ms**

**7  192.205.37.146 (192.205.37.146)  279.921 ms  280.059 ms  281.683 ms**

8  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  282.984 ms ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.9)  283.906 ms ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  284.473 ms

9  ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.9)  285.152 ms ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  285.917 ms  286.054 ms

10  a.resolvers.level3.net (4.2.2.1)  286.187 ms  286.935 ms  287.514 ms

IP Address: 192.205.37.146
[ IP Lookup ]
Hostname:   192.205.37.146
IP Location:    - United States (US) 
ISP:    AT&T Services
Organization:   AT&T Internet Services

### Well, this shows all sorts of latency in the First , Middle and Last mile.

- Trace In Progress

  traceroute to 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)  0.539 ms  0.696 ms  0.837 ms

**2     76-202-64-1.lightspeed.brbnca.sbcglobal.net (76.202.64.1)  201.040 ms
      201.634 ms  202.037 ms**

3  71.147.176.37 (71.147.176.37)  191.586 ms  192.707 ms  192.847 ms

4  75.20.0.202 (75.20.0.202)  195.827

ms  196.305 ms  196.800 ms

5  12.83.38.157 (12.83.38.157)  201.911
   ms 12.83.38.153 (12.83.38.153)  201.063 ms 12.83.38.157
   (12.83.38.157)  202.037 ms

6  ggr2.la2ca.ip.att.net
   (12.122.128.101)  201.354 ms  222.888 ms  226.604 ms

7 
   192.205.37.146 (192.205.37.146)  224.932 ms  222.087 ms  221.104 ms

8  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  223.069 ms 
   220.636 ms ae-3-80.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.137)  221.221 ms

9  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  221.632 ms  233.260 ms  144.725 ms

10  a.resolvers.level3.net (4.2.2.1)  143.808 ms  144.389 ms  144.739 ms

### Finally this last one shows a First and Middle but not a Last mile issue:

- Trace In Progress

  traceroute to 4.2.2.1 (4.2.2.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets

1  x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x)  1.184 ms  1.269 ms  1.408 ms

2  76-202-64-1.lightspeed.brbnca.sbcglobal.net (76.202.64.1)  288.124 ms  288.613 ms  290.000 ms

3  71.147.176.37 (71.147.176.37)  289.777 ms  302.201 ms  302.334 ms

4  75.20.0.202 (75.20.0.202)  305.836 ms  309.880 ms  310.032 ms

5  12.83.38.157 (12.83.38.157)  313.163 ms  312.685 ms  316.640 ms

6  ggr2.la2ca.ip.att.net (12.122.128.101)  328.398 ms  421.902 ms  420.155 ms

7  192.205.37.146 (192.205.37.146)  421.869 ms  21.274 ms  21.278 ms

8  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  23.584 ms  25.078 ms ae-1-60.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.9)  25.425 ms

9  ae-2-70.edge3.LosAngeles1.Level3.net (4.69.144.73)  26.380 ms  27.567 ms  28.278 ms

10  a.resolvers.level3.net (4.2.2.1)  27.654 ms  28.365 ms  28.907 ms

**If anyone can offer any insight on this circuit or path issue please give me some ideas... 
Thank you**

Comment: You should collect metrics to get a better idea of when this is happening and well as related stats such as packet loss and route instability. 200ms latency is not unreachability. Your edge router solution should be monitoring all these things already.

Comment: Right Mark, thanks for responding. What I'm trying to show here is the amount of variability in the circuit. These trace routes were done while the business was closed as well.